# Update inside foreach loop don't work more then one time

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've a problem with an mysql update query.
My code is:

```
public function update($idp, $ids){
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET idp = ? WHERE ids = ?";
    $atmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $atmt->bindParam(1, $idp, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $atmt->bindParam(2, $ids, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $atmt->execute();
    return 1;
}
```

My array of data is:

```
 [0]=>
 array(2) {
   ["id_s"]=>
   int(2)
   ["id_p"]=>
   int(111)
 }
 [1]=>
 array(2) {
   ["id_s"]=>
   int(3)
   ["id_p"]=>
   int(175)
 }
 [2]=>
 array(2) {
   ["id_s"]=>
   int(5)
   ["id_p"]=>
   int(25)
 }
 [3]=>
 array(2) {
   ["id_s"]=>
   int(7)
   ["id_p"]=>
   int(127)
 }
 ...
```

Walk on the array's elements and call the update method:

```
foreach($array as $index => $val){
        $idp = $id[$index]['id_p'];
        $ids = $id[$index]['id_s'];

        $admin->update($idp, $ids);
    }
```

I'd like to have a table like tihs:

```
ids | idp | other column
 1     5      ...
 3     97     ...
 3     97     ...
 4     32     ...
 5     178    ...
 5     178    ...
 5     178    ...
```

...

However with the foreach loop I update only the first record;
the array is ok with all values, it seem like the bind of parameters don't work.
Any solution?
Thanks!

Comment: you are returning inside your update function which is invoked inside your foreach loop , which will terminate the loop

Comment: What are `$array` and `$id`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel they are all int.

Comment: `foreach($array..` and `$id[$index]` - They can't be `int`. Or they shouldn't.

Comment: sorry, I mean that alla the values of the array are int, both id_p and id_p.

Comment: are you sure you want to assign `$idp` and `$ids` to a value from `$id`? (seems unrelated to your foreach loop).

Comment: array['id_s'] come from a select distinct(ids) from table, array['id_p'] are randomly generated and bind to each distinct id_s. When I try to update idp = id_p where ids = ids the query work only on first iteration (I tried to remove the return inside the update method but it's the same).